# Further Analysis of Regression Table

Tags: regression

After having run a factorial experiment, I have a regression table with the estimate, std error, t value and p value for two factors and their interaction. My analysis showed that the effect of one factor was larger at the lower level of the other. Is there a way to use this table to show whether this effect is significant (ie calculate the p value)?

Comment: Could you please provide more details about the experiment.

Comment: I meant could you show the data and the statistical analysis that was done.

Comment: I am not sure what you can do.  It looks like B has a larger effect than A but the interaction appears to be significant also.  It might be interesting to see what you get when you drop the interaction term.  How does that affect the t statistics for A and B?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "calculate the p value," given that you have already displayed four p-values for your analysis!

Comment: How many levels your factor has? I thought u should get a term for each interaction?

Comment: Can't you just plot it out in excel?  Then use the standard errors to construct a 95% confidence interval around the estimates.  If the confidence interval contains zero then the effect is not significantly different from zero.

I would do it myself but the coding scheme you have for the factors gives me pause.  With dummy variable coding it would be easy.  With this coding scheme I'm not as sure.  Maybe if you can elaborate on the coding scheme or post some sample data that would help.

Comment: Also, are these values made up?  I find the uniform .4 standard errors suspicious and an estimate that is less than it's standard error (as is the case for A:B) is not going to have a p value of .0034.  At least not to my knowledge.  I am no statistician though, so caveat emptor.